# Using socat to dump traffic to pcap

Tags: proxy, pcap, tcpdump, socat

Hi everyone this is my first question on stackoverflow!

I'm using [this](https://github.com/OwlH-net) software (it's a NIDS); one of its features is using socat to create a proxy that saves the traffic to a pcap.

That's the command it uses to do this: `/usr/bin/socat -d OPENSSL-LISTEN:50010,cipher=HIGH,method=TLS1.2,reuseaddr,pf=ip4,fk,cert=/usr/local/owlh/src/owlhnode/conf/certs/ca.pem,verify=0 SYSTEM:"/usr/sbin/tcpdump -n -r - -s 0 -G 50 -W 100 -w /usr/local/owlh/pcaps/remote-test%d%m%Y%H%M%S.pcap not port 22"`

That's what happens when using curl i try to make a request to google through the proxy:

```
╭─myasnik@tanuki ~/…/ossihr-poc/docker ‹master*›
╰─$ export https_proxy=https://0.0.0.0:50010/
╭─myasnik@tanuki ~/…/ossihr-poc/docker ‹master*›
╰─$ export http_proxy=https://0.0.0.0:50010/
╭─myasnik@tanuki ~/…/ossihr-poc/docker ‹master*›
╰─$ curl --proxy-insecure www.google.it
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

```
root@owlh-node:/# /usr/bin/socat -d OPENSSL-LISTEN:50010,cipher=HIGH,method=TLS1.2,reuseaddr,pf=ip4,fk,cert=/usr/local/owlh/src/owlhnode/conf/certs/ca.pem,verify=0 SYSTEM:"/usr/sbin/tcpdump -n -r - -s 0 -G 50 -W 100 -w /usr/local/owlh/pcaps/remote-test%d%m%Y%H%M%S.pcap not port 22"
tcpdump: unknown file format
2020/08/18 12:00:08 socat[1590] W system("/usr/sbin/tcpdump -n -r - -s 0 -G 50 -W 100 -w /usr/local/owlh/pcaps/remote-test%d%m%Y%H%M%S.pcap not port 22") returned with status 256
2020/08/18 12:00:08 socat[1590] W system(): No such file or directory
2020/08/18 12:00:08 socat[1589] E waitpid(): child 1590 exited with status 1
```

Thanks a lot for your help in advantage!

Comment: Make sure to actually have tcpdump installed on your system and that the path is `/usr/sbin/tcpdump` as expected.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i have it installed and the path is correct:
`root@owlh-node:/# which tcpdump
/usr/sbin/tcpdump`

Comment: I don't know much about `socat`, but whatever it's feeding `tcpdump` appears to be invalid data.  You get the same error message if you run `echo hello | tcpdump -r -`, so that seems to be the area you should focus on fixing.

Comment: I think the problem is that the `-r` option expects to read a **file**, but there's no libpcap header sent to tcpdump, so you could try somehow dumping a dummy libpcap header to tcpdump first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to the question, i think i misunderstood the way it was supposed to be done: https://github.com/OwlH-net/OwlH-Node/issues/47